# Unable to toggle state with React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean

I had to rewrite a class as a function in JS/React, but I am having some trouble to get the hook to work in the function.

```
function Switch(props) {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState();
  
  function handleClick() {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  }
 
  const className = `switch ${props.color} ${props.isActive ? 'on' : 'off'}`;

   return (
      <div className={className}>
        <button className="img" onClick={handleClick} />
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <Switch title="Happiness" color="blue" isActive={false} />
), document.querySelector('#root'));
```

I tried changing the handleClick function (and the setIsActive within it), but I can't get it to work. Thanks in advance for the help!

Note: Didn't add the CSS, as that part is working fine.

Comment: the current isActive state of your is empty tho, set it to false.
then in handleClick function write it like this setIsActive(prevState => !prevState)

Comment: Should the `Switch` be controlled or uncontrolled? Currently you are mixing both concepts by having the same value being passed as a prop as well as internal component state.

Comment: A value should only have one source. Decide whether `isActive` should be managed by this component (state) or something higher in the chain of components (props). If you mix them up you'll get into trouble sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking the isActive from props instead from state. To get this working you need to change

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState();
```

to

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(props.isActive);
```

and

```
const className = `switch ${props.color} ${props.isActive ? 'on' : 'off'}`;
```

to

```
const className = `switch ${props.color} ${isActive ? 'on' : 'off'}`;
```

Also if you want to apply prop changes from outside you need to add an useEffect hook as such

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsActive(props.isActive)
}, [props.isActive])
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a very bad practice. A proper way would be to pass a function that changes `isActive` through props so that the value has only one source.

Comment: @marzelin Yes lifting the state up would be cleaner. I just wanted to show a way without creating another component. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change props the component receives by a state within the child components. Props are(shall be) immutable. If you wish to alter the behaviour of component,

1. copy the props in the state variable

   `const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(props.isActive);`
2. use function form of state update. More important in cases where the new state depends on previous state

   `function handleClick() { setIsActive(prevState=>!prevState.isActive); }`
3. Update reference to state variable instead of received prop value

`const className =` switch ${props.color} ${isActive ? 'on' : 'off'}`;`

Answer (score 0):

You also need to look at component state isActive. You can logical Or it with your props isActive(which acts only as a default value here):

```
  const className = `switch ${props.color} ${
    props.isActive || isActive ? "on" : "off"
  }`;
```